# RabbitMQ delayed_message_exchange declaration fails in langohr clojure client

Tags: clojure, rabbitmq, langohr

I am trying to configure a RabbitMQ delayed message exchange as described in this document: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/

The below is my attempt at translating the code example from that README into clojure/langohr.

```
(let [conn (langohr.core/connect {:host "localhost" :port 61666})
      ch (langohr.channel/open conn)]
  (langohr.exchange/declare ch "my-exchange" "x-delayed-message"
                            {"x-delayed-type" "direct"}))
```

Sadly when I run this, I receive this error:

```
ShutdownSignalException channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - Invalid argument, 'x-delayed-type' must be an existing exchange type, class-id=40, method-id=10)  com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown (ChannelN.java:509)
```

Looking at the source for the rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message plugin, I can see that my `{"x-delayed-type" "direct"}` seems to be falling through to the default hander in that case statement.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/blob/543efef2555338c46f776a89df3ee134066221e2/src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl#L72

I've no idea why this is happening though, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to wrap the options map inside another `:arguments` map. Here's the [`langohr.exchange/declare` code](https://github.com/michaelklishin/langohr/blob/2f179e4a2da8d931bcd3bcf55e1e9317714e7c7d/src/clojure/langohr/exchange.clj#L71-L73) showing the call to `.exchangeDeclare` using the destructured `arguments` binding as a map.

```
(let [conn (langohr.core/connect {:host "localhost" :port 61666})
      ch (langohr.channel/open conn)]
  (langohr.exchange/declare ch "my-exchange" "x-delayed-message"
                            {:arguments {"x-delayed-type" "direct"}}))
```